# how to fix error 'QiskitBackendNotFoundError'

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, open-quantum-systems

This is my code:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q') 
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
```

```
QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ibmq_16_melbourne` was retired. You can see the list of [all the retired systems in this website](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources/docs/resources/manage/systems/retired-systems).

You can list of all the backends in your provider doing this:

```
[p.name() for p in provider.backends()]
```